# Error with programmatic views not sure what I am doing wrong. must call removeView() child already has a parent

Tags: java, android

I am having this issue while trying to programatically create a modular scrollview filled with buttons. My fragment accepts rows, columns, and names of each of the buttons. I am wondering why I get this runtime error with the following code.

**Error**

> The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView()
>   on the child's parent first.

**Code**

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    //linearLayout from scrollView
    LinearLayout linearVertical = 
    getActivity().findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_vertical);

    //LinearLayouts which will each contain buttons
    LinearLayout[] linearLayouts = new LinearLayout[mRows];

    //
    for(int i = 0; i < mRows; i++){
        linearLayouts[i] = new LinearLayout(getContext());
        linearLayouts[i].setLayoutParams(new 
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        linearLayouts[i].setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    }

    Button[] buttons = new Button[mRows * mColumns];

    //creating buttons / adding button style
    for(int i = 0; i < mRows * mColumns; i++){
        buttons[i] = new Button(getActivity(), null,R.style.buttonTheme);

        if(i < mNames.length){
            buttons[i].setText(mNames[i]);
        }else{
            buttons[i].setText("NULL");
        }

        buttons[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                buttonPress(v);
            }
        });
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < mRows; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < mColumns; j++){
            linearLayouts[i].addView(buttons[(i * j) + j]);
        }
        linearVertical.addView(linearLayouts[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the last loop as below and see if it works:

```
for(int i = 0; i < mRows; i++){
      linearVertical.addView(linearLayouts[i]);
        for(int j = 0; j < mColumns; j++){
            linearLayouts[i].addView(buttons[(i * j) + j]);
        }        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the parent from the Button when you want to add it to your LinearLayout. So, change the following:

```
for(int i = 0; i < mRows; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < mColumns; j++){
        linearLayouts[i].addView(buttons[(i * j) + j]);
    }
    linearVertical.addView(linearLayouts[i]);
}
```

to something like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < mRows; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < mColumns; j++){
        Button button = buttons[(i * j) + j];

        // Get the button parent
        ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) button.getParent();
        // remove the Button from the parent view.
        if(viewGroup != null) viewGroup.removeView(button);

        linearLayouts[i].addView(button);
    }
    linearVertical.addView(linearLayouts[i]);
}
```